# Async Socket server exits

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I am trying to create a async socket server but it does not wait for a client to connect and exits

```
class Program
{
        IPAddress ipadd;
        int port;
        TcpListener tcplistener;
        public async void startListeningForConnection(IPAddress ip = null, int dport = 23000)
        {
            if (ip == null)
            {
                ip = IPAddress.Any;
            }

            if (dport <= 0)
            {
                dport = 23000;
            }

            ipadd = ip;
            port = dport;

            tcplistener = new TcpListener(ipadd, port);


            try
            {
                tcplistener.Start();               
                Console.WriteLine("Ready to accept  client request.");
                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient clientResponse =await tcplistener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();                    
                    HandleClientRequest(clientResponse);//method displays the message from client
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void HandleClientRequest(TcpClient acceptReturn)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                stream = acceptReturn.GetStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                char[] buff = new char[64];
                Console.WriteLine("***Ready to read");
                while (true)
                {

                    int nRet = reader.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    if (nRet == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Socket disconnected");                        
                        break;
                    }
                    string receivedText = new string(buff);
                    Console.Write(receivedText);
                    Array.Clear(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    stream.Flush();                   
                }
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                tcplistener.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
            }
        }
```

When i run startListeningForConnection(), I get this:
Output:

```
Ready to accept  client request.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

it does not wait for a client to connect. If I remove the async and await then the program works as intended. Can anyone help me as it is my first socket program.

Comment: I suspect you're calling `startListeningForConnection` and just exiting. Change the return type to `Task` and await the call. Also, you almost never wait an `async void` method.

Comment: For testing purposes only, just remove async-await in the method and use:       TcpClient clientResponse = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();  , you might be able to catch exception.

Comment: @ATTA It works without exception and everything works fine if I remove async-await. But if I use async-await only then the program exits

Comment: At end of startListeningForConnection put a Console.ReadLine() and see if code works.  Nothing is blocking the code from exiting.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. it works. The main thread was not blocked. I have put a while(true); and now it works like a charm .